# Kodi refresh slideshow when folder content changes

Tags: slideshow, kodi

I use a Raspberry Pi to show a slideshow of pictures stored in a folder.

However, if I add pictures to the folder while the slideshow is running, the new pictures are not added to the slideshow.

How to achieve this behavior without interrupting the slideshow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an autostart script to Kodi: It will run the slideshow automatically when Kodi starts and refresh the slideshow if the content of the folder changes.

This script comes from this answer: https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/refresh-picture-library/4867/13

```
# ~/.kodi/userdata/autoexec.py
# On Kodi startup, automatically start a Slideshow
# Refresh the slideshow if the content of the folder has been updated

import xbmc
from os import listdir
from time import sleep

xbmc.log('[refresh-slideshow] Starting')

monitor = xbmc.Monitor()
picfolder = "/PATH/TO/FOLDER"

# Generate list of images and start slideshow
l1 = listdir(picfolder)
xbmc.executebuiltin('SlideShow(%s)' %(picfolder))
xbmc.log('[refresh-slideshow] Slideshow started, monitoring')

# Wait for slideshow to start
sleep(5)

# Monitor during slideshow
while not monitor.abortRequested():
    # If slideshow is still running, compare directory contents
    if xbmc.getCondVisibility('Window.IsActive(slideshow)'):
        l2 = listdir(picfolder)
        # Restart slideshow if directory contents have changed
        if l1 != l2:
            xbmc.log('[refresh-slideshow] Folder contents changed, restarting slideshow')
            xbmc.executebuiltin('SlideShow(%s)' %(picfolder))
            l1 = l2
    # If slideshow is no longer running (user has exited), exit script
    else:
        break

    # Wait for 60 seconds, break if abort is requested
    if monitor.waitForAbort(60):
        break

xbmc.log('[refresh-slideshow] Finished, exiting')
```

Comment: No need to restart the screensaver, you can automatically update/remove/change screensaver images when screensaver is active

Comment: Hi, when adding and removing images from the source folder, the slideshow does not update. Is it what you suggest ?

Comment: I personally don't think that `xbmc.getCondVisibility('Window.IsActive(slideshow)')` will show the correct status whether screensaver is active or not

Comment: Yes I did and the slideshow is correctly refreshing. Sorry I didn't give your solution a try yet.

Comment: You should try though

Comment: Does it crash or produce error ? I did not watch the logs, just wanted my slideshow to update and this goal is achieved.

I will try your solution

Comment: It does not even start and this condition is not satisfying at all

Comment: The slideshow does not autostart when you start Kodi with this script ? Wow we should not have the same version or you have missed something because it works fine on my side.

Answer (score 0):

### Convert your screensaver script in Class based if not.

### Create another class to update images using `threading`

```
import xbmc, xbmcgui, threading

class MyMonitor(xbmc.Monitor):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.action = kwargs['action']
    # do some action here.......

    def onScreensaverDeactivated(self):
        self.action()

class ImgVideoUpdate(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._get_items = kwargs['data']
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop = False
        self.check_update = 50  # set thread to update images(in seconds)
        self.Monitor = MyMonitor(action=self._exit)

    def run(self):
        while (not self.Monitor.abortRequested()) and (not self.stop):
            count = 0
            while count != self.check_update:  # check for new images every 50seconds
                xbmc.sleep(200)
                count += 1
                if self.Monitor.abortRequested() or self.stop:
                    return
            self._get_items()
```

## Now initialize `ImgVideoUpdate` in main `ScreensaverWindow` class from where screensaver is running

```
class ScreensaverWindow(xbmcgui.WindowXMLDialog):  
    def onInit(self):
        xbmcgui.WindowXML.onInit(self)
        self.volumeCtrl = None
        # Get the videos to use as a screensaver
        playlist = self.imagelist()
        thread = ImgVideoUpdate(data=self.imagelist)
        thread.start()
```

NOTE: Hope this helps.let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: "Convert your screensaver script in Class based if not."

By "screensaver" you mean "slideshow", right ?

Comment: What is the location of the scripts you wrote ? Where should I put them ?

Comment: @seza443 yes the main script in which you have inherit xbmcgui class